# How to put image and text over a coloured strip div with html and css?

Tags: html, css

I have created an orange coloured strip that goes the full width of the screen, but I have text and images underneath it that I want to bring to the front.

```css
.pumpkin1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-right: 110px;
}

#colourstrip {
  width: 1897px; height: 400px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(236, 117, 5);
  background-color: rgb(236, 117, 5);
  position: relative;
  top: -450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pumpkin1">
  <img src="/images/3.jpg" alt="AMD Ryzen 3 3200g" style="width: 235px;">
  <h2 style="font-size: 30px; padding-top: 35px;">AMD Ryzen 3 3200g</h2>
  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li style="position: relative; left: -30px"> Base 3.6GHz, Boost 4GHz</li>
    <li style="position: relative; left: -30px">4 Cores, 4 Threads</li>
    <li style="position: relative; left: -30px">65W TDP</li>
    <li style="position: relative; left: -30px">Socket AM4</li>
    <li style="position: relative; left: -30px">Wraith Stealth Air Cooler</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="colourstrip"></div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: You should really get your styles out of your markup. Use CSS classes. It's a much simpler way to work and makes upkeep far easier.

Comment: @UPinar, answers go down there. Ollie, please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Comment: You wouldn't normally add markup to put design elements in place. Instead, use a background strategy. Also, floats are an outdated layout technique. What is your intended outcome? It's not clear where the orang bar should be.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code a little bit. You don't even have to use z-index this way. Let me know how this works for you. I had to grab an image off the internet, cause your image wasn't loading properly. Doing it this way is better because your orange div won't have to be resized every time you add new content.

```css
.pumpkin1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(236, 117, 5);
  background-color: rgb(236, 117, 5);
}
div.pumpkin1 img {
  margin: 10px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pumpkin1">
    <img src="https://pisces.bbystatic.com/image2/BestBuy_US/images/products/6356/6356279_sd.jpg" alt="AMD Ryzen 3 3200g" width="235">
    <h2>AMD Ryzen 3 3200g</h2>
    <ul>
      <li> Base 3.6GHz, Boost 4GHz</li>
      <li>4 Cores, 4 Threads</li>
      <li>65W TDP</li>
      <li>Socket AM4</li>
      <li>Wraith Stealth Air Cooler</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Crimp, you should copy the original code down here and demonstrate your solution. It needs to fit the original intent.